# What's the Math / Algorithm Behind Photoshop's Selective Color Filter?

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, reverse-engineering, photoshop

I'm working on an image-processing software on iPhone and get stuck in the selective color function as photoshop.

How to caculate new RGB values after selective color adjustment on a pixel via code?

I mean how to create a tool which has the same function as Photoshop's selective color(In Image->Adjustment->Selective Color).

Special thx!

Comment: if you can, edit your question rather than extend it in comments.  Not everyone reads comments as closely as they read questions and answer, after all comments generally have a much lower SNR than Qs&As.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I sampled data of images which have be processed by photoshop, and got a quadratic curve with hue. But it is not exactly the same as photoshop's.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you replicate Photoshop's Selective Color?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a code which uses image buffer to manipulate alpha of an image but the same can be used to manipulate rgb as well  see this [link](http://codefriends.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-change-alpha-of-image.html)

See this sample it will give a general idea of image manipulation in objective c

Answer (score 0):

I too am trying to understand the math.  Here are some observations from experiments with pure colors in "Absolute" mode, which as an end user is all I care about

1) As expected, adding the opposite of any color turns the starting color black.  So 100% red + 100% cyan = black

2) Adding neighboring color does nothing.  So 100% red + any amount of yellow or magenta = 100% red

3) Adding triadic colors converts the primary color into a neighboring.  So 100% red + 100% green = 100% yellow

In RGB space this translates to something like

```
|r'|   |1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0|   |r|
|y'|   |0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1|   |y|
|g'|   |1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1|   |g|
|c'| = |1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1| * |c|
|b'|   |1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0|   |b|
|m'|   |0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1|   |m|
```

There is of course the adjustments for clipping, and black to white.  Here is a more mathy discussion

http://blog.pkh.me/p/22-understanding-selective-coloring-in-adobe-photoshop.html